# What is a projective resolution of $(x,y)$ and a $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$-module?

Tags: modules, projective-module

I have made the mistake multiple times of assuming that $(x,y)$ is a projective $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ module by thinking that $(x,y) \oplus \mathbb{C} \cong\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ as $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ modules, but I have been told this is false.

What then is a projective resolution of $(x,y)$ as a $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ module? I know that a free resolution exists, but how do I compute it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A= \mathbb C[X,Y]$, $I$ your ideal. There is a surjection $\varepsilon : A^2 \to I$ that assigns $(p,q) \longmapsto Xp+Yq$. What is its kernel? Try to continue this way. You cannot get past something of length two, so you haven't much work ahead.

Comment: I think the kernel is generated by $(Y,-X)$. But I do not see how this is projective (or free, for that matter).

Comment: It is, and there is now an injective map $A \longrightarrow A^2$ that sends $p$ to $(pY,-pX)$, and whose image is exactly the kernel.

Comment: When you say "it is" what do you mean? Do you mean "the kernel is generated b $(Y,-X)$? Do you mean "the kernel is projective"?

Comment: The kernel is free, and generated by $(Y,-X)$, as you said.